# Sort Elements jQuery Plugin, random sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am using this jQuery plugin to sort elements:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

It works well with this code:

```
function sortGallery(element, sorting) {

    $('input.sort').removeClass('active');
    $(element).addClass('active');

    if (sorting === 'bydate') {
        $('#gallery-js > div').sortElements(function(a, b){
            return $(a).find('img').attr('data-date') < $(b).find('img').attr('data-date') ? 1 : -1;
        });
    } else if (sorting === 'random') {
        console.log('TODO');
    }
}
```

The problem is I do not understand the return statement. Can someone tell me how the return value for the "random" part should look like and if possible a short description how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, first you might want to read up on how [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works.

In the documentation, they provide this code as an example as to how the sort order works

```
function compare(a, b) {
   if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion)
       return -1;
   if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion)
       return 1;
   // a must be equal to b
   return 0;
}
```

Since you want to just order randomly, all we need to do is generate a random integer from -1 to 1

```
function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Then you simply call the method like this

```
} else if (sorting === 'random') {
    return randomInt(-1, 1);
}
```

Comment: ok i dont understand it well.. but i guess thats becouse im not very good at those things. but it works and your description helps me enough to have a working code :) +1